The relation between locally finite algebras and group algebras of locally finite groups
Let $A$ be an algebra over a field $F$. Recall that $A$ is a locally finite algebra if every subalgebra of $A$ with finitely many generators has finite dimension over $F$. Meanwhile, $A$ is a group algebra of a group $G$ over $F$ if it is defined as a vector space over $F$ with the basis $G$ and the multiplicative is the linear extension of the rule $(ag)(bh)=abgh$ for $a b\in F$ and $g,h\in G$. We then write an element $\alpha\in A$ as $\alpha=\sum_{g\in G}a_gg$ in which the subset $\mathrm{supp}(\alpha)=${$g\in G\mid a_g\ne 0$} of $G$ is finite. A group $G$ is said to be locally finite if every subgroup of $G$ that is finitely generated is finite.
Now, we assume that $A$ is a group algebra of a locally finite group $G$ over $F$. Let $\alpha\in A$. Then, $\alpha=\sum_{g\in G}a_gg$ in which the subset $\mathrm{supp}(\alpha)=${$g\in G\mid a_g\ne 0$} of $G$ is finite. Put $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ generated by $\mathrm{supp}(\alpha)$. By definition, $H$ must be finite, and thus, the group algebra of $H$ over $F$ has finite dimension over $F$, especially, it is also a subalgebra of $A$.
With the observation at hand, I wonder if the class of group algebras of locally finite groups is contained in the class of locally finite algebras.
Any counterexample reference or technique is very much appreciated. I appreciate any help you can provide.

Your 'observation' is really almost a proof of what you're asking. Let $G$ be a locally finite group $A$ be a finitely generated subalgebra of $F[G]$. Let $\{\alpha_i:1 \leq i \leq n\}$ be a generating set for $A$. As you note, $supp(\alpha_i)$ is finite, so $S:= \bigcup_{i=1}^n supp(\alpha_i)$ is finite. Let $H$ be the subgroup generated by $S$. Then clearly $A \subseteq F[H]$, and $H$ is finite since $G$ is locally finite. It follows that $A$ is finite-dimensional over $F$, so $F[G]$ is locally finite.
You didn't ask this, but conversely, let $F[G]$ be locally finite as an algebra, and let $H$ be a finitely generated subgroup of $G$, say with generating set $S$. The subalgebra $F[H]$ is easily seen to be generated by $S$ as an algebra. By local finiteness, $F[H]$ is finite-dimensional so $H$ is finite.
So $F[G]$ is a locally finite algebra iff $G$ is a locally finite group.

Thank you for your great comment. I completely missed this detail. Furthermore, I wish to ask you if you know of any examples where a subalgebra of a group algebra isn't a group algebra.

However, I do not understand why $F[H]$ is finite-dimensional so H is finite. The set $H$ may not be a basis of $F[H]$. In an algebra, there may exist a finite generating set and another infinite generating set.

$F[H]$ is finite-dimensional because it is finitely generated by $S$, and it is a subalgebra of the locally finite algebra $F[G]$. From the definition of the group algebra, $H$ is always a basis of $F[H]$ so $dim(F[H])=|H|$.

Here is an example of a subalgebra of a group algebra which is not a group algebra. The group algebra of $\mathbb{Z}$ is isomorphic to $F[x,x^{-1}]$. This has a subalgebra $A=F[x]$. The set of units of $A$ is precisely $F^$, but clearly any group algebra of a nontrivial group will have units outside $F^$.

Thank you very much.
